# A few questions before I deploy this token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design

[image: solidity code]

A few concerns I have:

—Does this code look secure?

—Should the imported code version (0.8.0), the written code version (0.8.0), and the Remix compiler version (0.8.0) all be the same?

—Why does Max Total Supply show 0 in Etherscan testnet? I’m using Ropsten.

Thank you.

https://pastebin.com/i9Yy8QNX

Answer (score 1):

- OpenZeppelin is a “battle-tested” open source framework comprised of reusable Ethereum smart contracts. The framework helps smart contract developers reduce the risk of vulnerabilities in their distributed applications (dapps) by using standard, tested, community-reviewed code.
- Yes, it should be the same.
- There is a bug in testnets since a lobg time which shows max total supply as 0. I'm sure if you test it with out networks like Kovan or BSC  you won't see 0 max supply.